# Can I use a single battery charging ic to charge two batteries in parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, lipo

I am making a wearable device so for better space distribution I would like to use two smaller batteries instead of a big one. I've been using TinyCircuits's ASR00007 (290mA, lipo) battery which has a charger ic recommended. Can I simply connect two smaller batteries to the end in paralell?
(Datasheet to the battery: https://hu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/855/ASR00007_290mAh-3078659.pdf)

[image: TinyCircuits's ASR00007 battery charger]

Comment: What Saadat said - they should be same brand same model same type in every way, and charged to identical states before they are connected. If you wanted to be very sure you could balance them after that by placing a resistor between the two batteries until no current flows between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Li-Pol and Li-ion batteries, yes. Just make sure they are charged at the same level and are on the same voltage the first time you are connecting them together.

Making them parallel makes them the same as a battery with double capacity. It will just be a little bigger than one battery with the same capacity.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Yes it will be a bit bigger in overal size, but with two smaller ones I can make them more curved so they fit better on a wrist.

Comment: In general, however, you should never do this with batteries of unknown provenance. Only with brand-new batteries that have never been charged or discharged before (or at least that have always been connected in parallel since they were new). Preferably identical ones from the same lot, too.